# Remove item from Replay Observable

Tags: buffer, system.reactive, replay

Imagine you have a replay observable, created through one of the [`Replay` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.replay.aspx).
Is there a variant of `Replay` that produces a replay observable with a method that lets me remove an item/message/element from the replay buffer?

I need the replay observable in order to avoid a race condition: two observables `A` and `B` produce related messages. If `A` produces a message `m`, then `B` may follow suit with a corresponding message `m'` (but that's optional).
In order to filter out `m'` from all of `B`'s messages, the subscriber to `A` registers a subscriber with `B` (filtered for the exact `m'` message), since only when `m` is received will the program be able to predict what a potentially incoming `m'` will look like.

However, sometimes `m'` arrives even before the subscriber to `A` was scheduled to run, meaning there is no subscriber for `m'` registered yet. I can solve this by wrapping `B` as a replay observable, but I want to be able to clean up processed messages from the replay buffer, because I know each of `B`'s messages will be processed by exactly one subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = foo.Replay().Where(x => x != skip);
```

Comment: I think this will not solve my problem: My original observable is ongoing, meaning the first replay-wrapper around it will not be disposed of, until all of its subscribers are gone. So if I just keep on adding layers of filtered replay-wrappers, the inner layers will accumulate forever.

Comment: Actually, just re-read your problem. Have you considered using `IObservable.Zip()`?

Comment: I considered, then discarded the idea :) For `Zip`to work, i need to *always* have an `m'` (for each `m`). But the `m'` is optional

Comment: When you say optional, does the consumer know if it is optional? Because the `m'` subscription could then be kludged to return a null `m'` when it isn't required...Or even use a different observer/subscriber pair, then join them up again...

Comment: The incoming `m` will only allow to predict how to identify/filter out the corresponding `m'`, should one arrive. It can't be used predict whether or not it *will* come